# Operator to concatenate two dbt Jinja sets?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

In a given model, I am using two macros to create sets for a later loop.

Adapting [the example](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros#set-variables-at-the-top-of-a-model) from the docs, it looks something like this:

```
{% set pay_1 = ["bank_transfer"] %}
{% set pay_2 = ["credit_card", "gift_card"] %}
{% set payment_methods = pay_1 + pay_2 %}

{% for payment_method in payment_methods %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

What is the syntax for the pseudo code `pay_1 + pay_2` to combine these two set variables as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as written works.  The value of `payment_methods` at the end of your code is

```
['bank_transfer', 'credit_card', 'gift_card']
```

It's worth pointing out that these are lists, not sets. If items are duplicated across your list, they will be duplicated in the result.  As far as I know, there is not support for sets in dbt-jinja.

Comment: First, wow can't believe I didnt just try to run it because that's awesome
Second, hmm you are right. That is a confusing usage of the term `set` if it generates a list .... seems like `assign` or similar would work better here?

Comment: I can see how that might be confusing, but that's just the syntax that Jinja uses for assignment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#assignments